# Simple question about inner product spaces

Tags: inner-products

$$|\langle x,y\rangle|^2\leq\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle$$ Is true in any inner product space, please if someone can show me how to prove the next statement out of the first one $$\sqrt{\langle x+y,x+y \rangle}\le \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle} + \sqrt{\langle y,y \rangle}$$

I hope I've been clear enough, Thanks.

Comment: Square both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square both sides.  Note that
$$
\langle x+y,x+y \rangle = 
\langle x,x+y \rangle + \langle y,x+y \rangle =\\
\langle x,x \rangle +
\langle x,y \rangle +
\langle y,x \rangle + 
\langle y,y \rangle
$$
And that
$$
\langle x,y \rangle +
\langle y,x \rangle = 
2 \text{Re} (\langle x,y \rangle) \leq 2\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle \langle y,y\rangle}
$$

Comment: Ok, so how do I use then the first equation in the second I am a little confused :)

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: And so what now, this doesn't help me.

Comment: Square and expand both sides.  Write both out completely, and edit those into your question.  If you don't see the answer at that point, I'll just write it out.

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now please just tell me how you got the last inequality you wrote, with the real part?

Comment: $\langle y,x \rangle = \overline{\langle x,y \rangle}$.  And, for any $z \in \Bbb C$, Re$(z) \leq |z|$.

Comment: I finally see it, Thanks:)